# Как получить ответ на команду отправленную в Com порт

Tags: c#, serial

Всем привет.

Необходимо сделать свой "велосипед" по приему/отправке смс сообщений. загвоздка в следующем: я выполняю AT команду(отправка СМС в формате PDU) но не знаю через сколько придет ответ.
алгоритм примерно следующий:

```
var sp = new SerialPort();
//производим настройку: устанавливаем скорость, биты данных, четность и т.п.
sp.Open();
if(sp.IsOpen)
{
    sp.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");
    sp.Write("AT+CMGS=118\r");
    sp.Write("07919772099090F031000B811032547698F000080B68041C0435043D044F00200437043E0432044304420020042104350431043E04410442044C044F043D0020041F04350440043504390440043E002D0442043E04400433043E0432043504460020044704350440043D044B043C002004340435044004350432043E043C\x1A");
}
```

в ответ должно прийти: "***+CMGS:158***" или  +"***CMS ERROR: текст ошибки***"
где 158 число в диапазоне 0..255(индекс сообщения)
как мне встать в режим ожидания ответа на отправленную команду.

Заранее спасибо

P.S. если будет пример буду премного благодарен.

**Update**

пока получается как то так:

```
public class SMS
{
    public string Phone {get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
    public DateTime Sent {get;set;}
    public DateTime? Delivery {get;set;}
}

public class GSMModem
{
    //Строка куда будем записывать полученные данные
    private string response = string.Empty;
    private SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
    private Queue<SMS> outgoingMessages = new Queue<SMS>();
    private Queue<SMS> sentMesssages = new Queue<SMS>();

    public IsOpen
    {
        get
        {
            return sp.IsOpen;
        }
    }   

    void Open()
    {
        sp.Open()
        if(IsOpen)
        {
            sp.DataReceived+=ReceivingData;
        }
    }

    void Close()
    {
        sp.DataReceived-=ReceivingData;
    }

    void ReceivingData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            response = sp.ReadExisting();
            if(response.Contains("+CMGS:"))
            {
                //в случае успешной отправки убираем сообщение
                //из очереди на отправку в отправленные сообщения
                var message = outgoingMessages.Dequeue()
                sentMesssages.Enqueue(message);
            }
            else if(response.Contains("+CMTI:"))
            {
                //Входящее сообщение
            }
            else if(response.Contains("+CUSSD:"))
            {
                //USSD запрос
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {}
        finally
        {}
    }

    bool ExecuteATCommand(string atCommand)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if(IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                sp.DiscardInBuffer();
                sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
                sp.Write(atCommand + "\r");
                result = true;
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {}
            finally
            {}          
        }
        return result;
    }

    void SendMessage(string phone, string message)
    {
        var message = outgoingMessages.Peek()
        var pduMessage = new PDU.Encoding(message.Phone, message.Message);
        ExecuteATCommand("AT+CMGF=1")
        ExecuteATCommand("AT+CMGS="+pduMessage.Length.ToString());
        ExecuteATCommand(pduMessage.ToString());
    }
}
```

правда не знаю как обработать ситуацию когда модем не ответил на посланную команда вообще никак, т.е. "завис". может кто нибудь подскажет как обработать такую ситуацию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Использовать событие `DataReceived`, которое вызывается при поступлении количества байт, заданного в свойстве `ReceivedBytesThreshold`.

```
public void Communicate() {
    var sp = new SerialPort();
    sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
    //далее Ваш код настройки и отправки данных
}

private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                    object sender,
                    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    Console.Write(indata);
}
```

При этом важно, чтобы поток не был убит до окончания необходимых Вам коммуникаций. В частности, этот вариант будет полезен в приложении с графическим интерфейсом. Хотя общая рекомендация для всех вариантов - выполнять обмен с устройствами ввода-вывода в отдельном потоке, если у Вас есть графический интерфейс. Это поможет исключить "зависание" приложения.

**Вариант 2**

Делать блокирующий вызов `Read`:

```
sp.Read(buffer, 0, 4); // читаем 4 байта для примера
```

Минус - блокирующий вызов из-за которого приложение "повиснет", если будет выполнен в основном потоке. При этом вызовет `TimeoutException`, если свойство `ReadTimeout` у `SerialPort` отличен от `SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout` и прошло это время.

**Вариант 3**

Проверять значение свойства `BytesToRead` в цикле:

```
while (sp.BytesToRead == 0) {
    // ничего нет
}
// что-то пришло, делаем sp.Read(...)
```

По сути аналог предыдущего варианта, только без встроенной реализации таймаута.

Comment: уже наметился на использование стандартного события DataReceived но возник небольшой вопрос. в данном глобальном событии я буду получать данные и в соответствии с тем что пришло вызывать другие события и соответственно обрабатывать их(прием смс/отчет о доставке и т.п.) а как обработать что ничего не произошло в опр. промежутке времени.ну например железка просто повисла?!

Comment: Записываете куда-то время последней команды и ставите таймер. Если ответ пришел - отключаете таймер. В противном случае делаете вывод, что с железка не отвечает. Посмотрите класс `Timer` для примера. Если нужно подробнее, то создайте отдельный вопрос.